# Filestream renaming file

Tags: c#, file, filestream

I'm trying to read a file as filestream, renaming the file, and send the file in the form of filestream to a Document Management System(DMS).

I've seen so many questions in StackOverflow asking about renaming the file in c#, and most of the reply suggested using File.Move .

However, I was wondering If don't want to actually rename the file, and I would like rename to file once the file has become filestream. I want to explore the alternative solution other than File.Move.

I've tried to rename the file by the following approach, however, It seems that the name property of filestream object is read-only.

```
//This is my attempt
FileStream fs = new FileStream()
fs.Name = "new_name" //<-- not working
```

Additional Info:

Yes, I'm now trying to amend some legacy code without proper documentation, where the code apparently indicated that the library of the DMS has a parameter to pass a filestream object into it and upload. Therefore, I assumed the DMS does read the Name property of the filestream.

The reason why I want to directly change the name of the filestream is that I want to change at least as possible since the one who wrote this code has already gone and I also don't have the document of the DMS. Also, the document will be stored after finished uploading, this is the reason why I don't want to change to name of the document.

```
//This is how the actual program code looked like
FileStream input = File.OpenRead(uploadFile_path);
obj.Update();
obj.Fetch();
```

But after listening to all your suggestion, I think the safest way to solve this problem will be:

1. Create a copy of the file
2. Rename the copy of the file
3. Upload the filestream of the file
4. Remove the file

Comment: What is a *DMS* (for the uninitiated)

Comment: Do you mean that `fs.Name` is used elsewhere in your code to determine its name in the DMS?

Comment: @TheGeneral I'm guessing "document management system"

Comment: @John oh i see!

Comment: Unsafe way with potentially unexpected results, and with to be different in future .NET implementations/other .NET implementations (e.g. Mono): use reflection to set the value of the private `_filename` field. Safe way: wrap it in an object that carries the desired DMS name. Alternative safe way: copy the file to a temp location with the new name, delete it when done.

Comment: when it's a stream, it's not really a file, it's just some binary data. Why not rename it first, and then grab the stream using the new name?

Comment: @John Sorry for using ambiguous short form, I thought people might understand DMS stand for "document management system"

Comment: @ADyson It's because I want to make at least changes as possible to the already existing program code.

Comment: @Matthew111 why is that a useful goal, in your opinion? Make the changes which are necessary. If you test them properly, document them and commit them to source control as a single, coherent set of changes which just implement this specific requirement then it should not matter what you change. Even if you do what I suggested, it's hardly a big alteration, is it? And the DMS will not see any difference at all - it will just see a filestream with a name. It won't have any idea you renamed it before sending it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your document management system (DMS apparently) is using the [`FileStream.Name Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.name?view=netframework-4.7.2) (which seems weird to say the least) you are out of luck, this can't be changed (easily).

- You will have to see if there is an override to take the file name in your DMS call
- Or rename it before you open it

E.g

```
System.IO.File.Move("oldfilename", "newfilename");
```

Or because this is stackoverflow, you could set the name with reflection

***Note*** : i do not recommend this, this may change with future versions of .net, and who knows what issues you could have, however it does work to change the Name property

```
// some FileStream 
FileStream file = new FileStream(@"D:\test.txt", FileMode.Open);

var myField = file.GetType()
                  .GetField( "_fileName", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)

// set the name
myField.SetValue(file, "blah");
```

Comment: Do to your warning I'm hesitant to use this method.  However, I have a need to do exactly this!  I have a file that I do not want to disturb (various reasons, read-only access and I just want everything to stay the same from the source files.  However, apparently the place this filestream/byte array ends up they ignore the meta data and check the actual file name.  So I need to get the file in memory, change the name in memory, then turn it into a byte array.  Is there anything that has changed in ~2.5 years that would make this answer better?  Thanks!

Comment: @ArvoBowen no there is no new way of dealing with this as far as i know. Note that for a limited use case for 3rd party apis this might be suitable. Although this ***can*** change in future versions is unlikely ***to*** change at least with the Microsoft implementation of the CLR . What i suggest you do if this is going into production, is to just write unit tests for it, at least that way you will have more confidence this is working on a release to release basis

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions #1 (I got lazy trying to type the binary).